# Hyperledger Consensus - how does it work?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, consensus

Here is our use-case:
Anna would like to sell her shares to Peter, and Olga needs to approve it (as an owner of the company).

How would that work on blockchain hyperledger fabric/composer with consensus?

In particular, what part of that is a transaction, what is a proposal (is a proposal requires a physical approval of a transaction by a living person?) and how is that handled on blockchain, what happens in the application and outside of the application.

Please be as specific as possible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A few things first:
Composer uses whatever consensus algorithm the underlying blockchain is configured to use. So; Hyperledger Fabric at the moment offers SOLO or KAFKA. 
KAFKA offers fault tolerance only, not byzantine fault tolerance.

So:
Endorsement Policies do exist which is what you are describing. It does not require approval by a living person, you can make everything programmatic, it could even be an IoT device. The approver must simulate the transaction and see if they agree with the output. Olga is the approver in your scenario.

It's important to make all chaincode (transactions in Composer) deterministic, so they can be simulated in that way.

There is a good description on transaction flow on Fabric's docs: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html

I'm releasing a paper in a month that has a section on consensus comparisons and Composer/Fabric specifically. I can send you a draft if you're interested further.

Comment: Thank you! And a draft of the paper would be great! We have checked the link, but it's still a bit confusing.

Comment: c.mcqueen@newcastle.ac.uk - drop me an email and I'll send you over the current version

Essentially; what you are suggesting is possible and fits well with endorsement policies. The huge caveat is that I discovered is the endorsers for a transaction type must be specified when you deploy the network. They can not be dynamic (e.g. If Anna sells her shares to Olga, Peter is the endorser)

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to your question, one is the approval aspect of a living person and second is the integrity of the ledger state (consensus).

I will explain in the reverse order.

**Consensus Part**

So Hyperledger Fabric is an enterprise solution that targets to maintain a consistent ledger on which all organization of the consortium needs to agree upon. This is achieved by combining the ledgers of multiple organization into one ledger and the transactions recorded in this one ledger will include transaction from each party.

These transactions are not random transactions but rather implementation of Smart Contract called chaincode in Fabric terminology. Whenever a chaincode is deployed on a Fabric channel(a private subnet associated with its own ledger) it initializes the World State i.e default assets and their values.

Next each organization agree upon an endorsement policy, for example 1 peer from each organization should endorse the transaction(called transaction proposal in this state), the endorsement is simply a read-write set of the transaction having read set(values of assets before transaction simulation), write set(values of assets after the transaction simulation). If the endorsement from all peers(all those peers that satisfy the endorsement policy) is same, which means the world state of assets is consistent across all the peers(atleast those that satisfy endorsement policy) and hence ledger data integrity is achieve.

The consensus further includes batching transactions into blocks and ordering of the transactions within the block by ordering service which validates the endorsers signatures again and the World State validation is done one final time when the block reaches peers for committing.

**Approval part**

When you have an approval process that requires a participant interaction, it is something that you will have to take care of in your chaincode. Composer is the best place to start.

From Composer examples look at the CarAuction example and you will understand the for each state transition you will have to have registery e.g a seller participant owns an asset Car but when the Car is auctioned for selling it has to be added to a listing registry using transaction where it will be visible to all bidder participants, this movement of state of Car asset is achieved by a transaction `AuctionMyCardOrSomething` invoked by authorized party here seller. Then when the Auctioneer(another participant with a different role) executes another transaction called closed bidding then the Car ownership can be transferred to the highest bidder if all conditions are satisfied. Node that placing a bid is also a transaction.

Pay attention the the Auctioneer and state transitions in this example and the same model can be applied to your case. Each time state transition is required you have to execute a transaction and update the ledger.

Hope this helps.